# Error using for loop in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi

```
    for ( int iIdx = 0; iIdx < argc; ++iIdx )
    _tprintf( TEXT( "Arg %d: %s\n" ), iIdx, argv[ iIdx ] );
_tprintf( TEXT( "\n" ) );
```

Is this valid in C? Because I get an error when I try to compile it, if I remove the int from the initializer section of the for loop, it compiles fine...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not valid in C before C99.

In C89/90 and earlier, declarations need to be at the start of each block. You can't interleave declarations and normal code.

A declaration inside the `for` does not count as being at the start of a block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Microsoft's C compiler (`cl`) does not support modern C ([C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)).  For loop initializers like that are new in C99.

Comment: Why won't they support modern C? I'm using VS 2010 btw

Comment: @shawn, good question.  There are many [bug reports](http://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+site%3Aconnect.microsoft.com+c99&oq=microsoft+site%3Aconnect.microsoft.com+c99) about this in Microsoft Connect.

Comment: @shawn: They prefer to focus their efforts on the C++ compiler. So C doesn't get much attention.